# Terraform unable to enable AWS redis elasticache transit_encryption_enabled for created cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elasticache

We are running AWS redis v7 elasticache with engine_version 7.0, now we want to enable `transit_encryption_enabled` without recreating resource.

This modification we are able to do with aws cli and aws console from which we are restricted to proceed aside terraform throws irrelevant error, it's not modifying nor destroying first and then creating, we will lose data if we recreate so we want to just modify.

**NOTE**: Even adding `lifecycle {create_before_destroy = true}` didn't help.

```
aws_elasticache_replication_group.cache_cluster: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating ElastiCache Replication Group (service-cluster): ReplicationGroupAlreadyExists: Replication group with specified name already exists.
│       status code: 400, request id: 15387a2d-3719-4279-8b66-914733b78e80
│ 
│   with aws_elasticache_replication_group.cache_cluster,
│   on main.tf line 155, in resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "cache_cluster":
│  155: resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "cache_cluster" {
```

Resource block:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "cache_cluster" {
  replication_group_id       = "service-cluster"
  auto_minor_version_upgrade = false
  description                = module.cache_cluster.merged.description
  node_type                  = module.cache_cluster.merged.node_type
  port                       = module.cache_cluster.merged.port
  engine_version             = module.cache_cluster.merged.engine_version
  parameter_group_name       = module.cache_cluster.merged.parameter_group_name
  snapshot_retention_limit   = module.cache_cluster.merged.snapshot_retention_limit
  snapshot_window            = module.cache_cluster.merged.snapshot_window
  maintenance_window         = module.cache_cluster.merged.maintenance_window
  multi_az_enabled           = module.cache_cluster.merged.multi_az_enabled
  automatic_failover_enabled = module.cache_cluster.merged.automatic_failover_enabled
  at_rest_encryption_enabled = module.cache_cluster.merged.at_rest_encryption_enabled
  transit_encryption_enabled = module.cache_cluster.merged.transit_encryption_enabled
  subnet_group_name          = aws_elasticache_subnet_group.cache_subnet.name
  security_group_ids         = module.vpc.vpc_security_groups.ids
  kms_key_id                 = module.kms_cmk_cache.kms_key_arn
  tags                       = merge(module.tags.merged, var.platform_mandatory_tags)
  apply_immediately          = module.cache_cluster.merged.apply_immediately
  replicas_per_node_group    = module.cache_cluster.merged.replicas_per_node_group
  num_node_groups            = module.cache_cluster.merged.num_node_groups


  log_delivery_configuration {
    destination      = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cache_cluster_slow_log.name
    destination_type = "cloudwatch-logs"
    log_format       = "json"
    log_type         = "slow-log"
  }
  log_delivery_configuration {
    destination      = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cache_cluster_engine_log.name
    destination_type = "cloudwatch-logs"
    log_format       = "json"
    log_type         = "engine-log"
  }

}
```

**tfvars**:

```
cache_cluster = {
  description                = "service cluster"
  node_type                  = "cache.t3.micro"
  port                       = 6379
  engine_version             = "7.0"
  parameter_group_name       = "default.redis7.cluster.on"
  snapshot_retention_limit   = 1
  snapshot_window            = "00:00-05:00"
  maintenance_window         = "sun:05:00-sun:09:00"
  multi_az_enabled           = true
  automatic_failover_enabled = true
  num_node_groups            = 2
  replicas_per_node_group    = 1
  at_rest_encryption_enabled = true
  transit_encryption_enabled = true
  apply_immediately          = true

}
```

Am aware that using aws cli with terraform null_resource would work but only aws cli > v2.9x supports it but our system as of now supports only < v2.8x so please suggest if there is a way to get this working.

I observed transit_encryption_enabled has `preferred` and `required` modes on aws console and aws cli but missing in terraform.

Comment: Can you add the entire resource block to the question?

Comment: @MarkoE added the tf resource block, thankyou.

Comment: Where are all the module outputs you are referencing coming from?

Comment: @MarkoE   module "cache_cluster" {
  source = "./modules/terraform-null-deepmerge"
  maps = [
    var.cache_cluster,
    var.deep_merge_configs.cache_cluster,
  ]
}

Comment: And terraform-null-deepmerge just concatenates the tfvars i shared in the description already

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this correctly, but you are using a terraform module full of null_resource just so you can concatenate variables?

Comment: I think we are deviating from the question @MarkoE, we did it according to our requirement with "locals" as it is not just a single piece of code there are multiple resources used for our need, I can't share complete code, whichever way values are getting substituted I anyways shared the tfvars that we substituting, lets comeback to the actual concern in question please.

Comment: The ability to change transit-encryption-enabled and transit-encryption-mode for existing clusters was introduced in version 2.9.12 of the AWS CLI.